# VB how to add a list item to a class

Tags: vb.net

No so familiar with VB how would one add to a list in a class item ?

```
 public class Demo
   public Property Id as Integer
   public RevsList as List (of ProjectItem)
 end Class

 public class ProjectItem
   public Property Rev as Integer
   public Title as string
 end Class
```

With code i try to ad a ProjectItem to the Revslist

```
 Dim revision as new Demo With {.id = 1}
 revision.RevsList.Add(new ProjectItem() With {.Rev =33, .Title="description"})  '<= what is the correct syntax todo this
```

Hod does one add a item to such a list.

Comment: "not working" is never an acceptable description of a problem.

Comment: Well what should the syntax be

Comment: why so mean ?, trying to code here in a language i'm not often using.

Comment: You should add the error you are getting. You declare the list but don't seem to create it anywhere. `public RevsList as List (of ProjectItem) = new List (of ProjectItem)`

Comment: As edited, this no longer has a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed out a separator and a dot before the title variable....

```
Dim revision as new Demo With {.id = 1}
revision.RevsList.Add(new ProjectItem() With {.rev =33, .title="description"})
```

I also notice that you have declared `RevsList` in your demo class, but not initialised it.
You can either do that in the demo class but using the `New` keyword:

```
public class Demo
   public Property Id as Integer
   public RevsList as New List (of ProjectItem)
end Class
```

Or you can do it before adding anything to it:

```
Dim revision as new Demo With {.id = 1}
revision.RevsList = New List(of ProjectItem)
revision.RevsList.Add(new ProjectItem() With {.Rev =33, .Title="description"})
```

EDIT

If you are still having issues, try creating the ProjectItem before adding it. It is a bit more verbose, but is arguably easier to read:

```
    Dim revision As New Demo
    revision.Id = 1

    Dim NewProjectItem As New ProjectItem
    NewProjectItem.Rev = 33
    NewProjectItem.Title = "description"

    revision.RevsList.Add(NewProjectItem)
```

Comment: (i added but it had no effect, it was there in my code, but as typo not in this post)

Comment: Well, that is the correct syntax. So if you are still having issues, your problem must be elsewhere. What .NET version are you using? What error (or suggested fix) is VS showing? I have updated my answer with an alternative (more verbose) option.

Comment: I was convinced as well, i rewrote the code added a constructor to ProjectItem.
Then i created a seperate list to add new project items in.
Then that list i assigned to revslist ... i'm puzled, but i'll mark your reply as answer cause i still think it is suposed to work that way too.

Comment: What .NET version are you using? Not sure if it makes a difference, but they may have added/changed the inline `WITH` syntax at some point.